# Type shift in Flash

Tags: flash, macos, text, flash-cs5

HI all,

I just bought a flash template and upon trying to edit it on my mac, I see that all text items have shifted up on the stage. However if I open the same package on a Windows box the text appears to be normal.

Is there anything I can do on my mac to prevent this from happening?

TIA

Michel

Comment: Is it a FLA template, or an SWF that takes some sort of text file as input?

Comment: The package includes both. The swf is showing fine on either platform, it is only the FLA that causes problems once opened on my mac... Mind you if I nudge all the text and re-publish, thye end product will look fine... Another thing to consider, the template I bought was created on Flash CS4, both my mac and PC are running CS5.

Comment: Are the TextFields themselves displaced (do the coordinates differ), or does the font render differently?

Answer (score 2):

This problem has been around for a long time (Mario Klingemann blogged about it back in 2004! http://www.quasimondo.com/archives/000386.php). I believe it has something to do with subtle differences in fonts across platforms. I think it's the OTF fonts that work better than TTF across platforms.

An obvious solution would be to swap the font to one that displays ok on both PC and MAC, but that might ruin the design.

Another option might be to have one instance of the textfield in your library, that all textfields use, which means you'd only have to change the alignment in one place, but this isn't ideal either, especially if you have different font sizes and if textfields aren't dynamic.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I can't believe it's 2015 already and this is still a problem after MORE THAN A DECADE! And still Adobe did absolutely nothing to fix this during all these years (even Flash Pro CC, released in 2014, still has this issue). I've seen in that 2004 blog post that they link to a JSFL script that might fix the problem, but the link to the MXP is of course dead. Does anyone still have that script?